# How to abruptly stop a linear animated jQueryUI slider handle (crossbrowser)

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, css-transitions

We are using the [jQuery slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) for our slideshow. Now, the handle is animated during playback. But if the user pauses, the handle should be set to a stationary position immediately (i.e. the animation should be stopped).

At first, I thought, this would be easiest to use the `animate` option (http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-animate) from the slider. But I did not find a way to create a **linear** animation.

Therefore, we have solved this issue by now using CSS transitions. If the slider is playing, a CSS transition class is added to the handle. If the slider is paused, the CSS class is removed and the slider handle jumps into position immediately.

This works fine with Chrome and Safari, but unfortunately not with Firefox or InternetExplorer. They don't stop the handle immediately, but run the animation to the end, which is confusing because the handle does not react immediately to the user action.

---

**The current JavaScript code for switching the CSS in the jQuery slider looks like this:**

```
$slider.on('change.mode', function(event, playing){
    if(playing)
        $(this).addClass('playing');
    else
        $(this).removeClass('playing');
});
```

**The CSS looks like this:**

```
.playing .ui-slider-handle {
    #x-browser > .transition(1s, linear, left); //LESSCSS Shortcut
}
```

**You can view a live example of the complete player here:**

http://lookr.com/1239271528

---

It works in Chrome and Safari, but can anyone tell me how to make this work in Firefox and Internet Explorer?

---

## Update

**Maybe the real question here should be: how to stop a CSS animation for sure in all browsers immediately?**

Comment: You could animate one step at a time, and after each animation do a check if the playing "status" is still true, then animate one more step. This would make sure the animation stops at each step

Comment: Do you want a jQuery or CSS solution?

Comment: @Dom: Either jQuery or CSS would be fine

Comment: @Slugge: OK, but this would interfere with the already available jQuery slider API. I still want to use it as-it-is as much as possible.

Comment: jQuery slider is able to move in steps https://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$slider.on('change.mode', function(event, playing){
    if(playing){
        $(this).addClass('playing');
        $(this).find('.ui-slider-handle').addClass('stop'); //ADDED
    }
    else{
        $(this).removeClass('playing');
        $(this).find('.ui-slider-handle').removeClass('stop');  //ADDED
    }
});
```

---

CSS (ADDED)

```
.stop {
     transition:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be oversimplifying things, but you could try something like this:

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/8hAQg/4/)

JS

```
// shows values in the demo
var showAmount = function (event, ui) {
    $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    $("#amount2").val(parseInt($('.ui-slider-handle').css('left'), 10));
};
$(function () {
    $("#slider").slider({
        animate: 5000, //slowed down to 5s for demo only, for normal timing set to true
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 500, // make the max value the same as the width
        slide: showAmount,
        change: showAmount
    });

});

// click to trigger animation to 500
$("#play").click(function () {
    $("#slider").slider("value", 500);
});

// click to set the value of the slider to the handles left position
$("#stop").click(function () {
    $("#slider").slider('option', "value", parseInt($('.ui-slider-handle').css('left'), 10));
});
```

CSS

```
#slider {
    width: 500px; /* must match the max value of the slider */

}
```

This method kind of hinges on being able to set the maximum value of slider to match the width of the slider. If that's not a big problem the left position of the slider's handle will match the value of the slider and you can use that as a stopping value.

Tested and working in IE9/10, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Very nice, but at the same time, the slider needs the given breakpoints (24 for the last day, 30 for the last month) where the slider needs to snap in position. This is not possible with this approach, right?

Comment: @SimonFerndriger can you set up a fiddle with what you have so far?

Comment: I'm afraid the whole player which is involved would be too overwhelming for an easy-to-understand fiddle... - I guess the solution needs to be based conceptual only.

Comment: But the desired end result is always visible on http://lookr.com/1239271528 (using Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than animation you could try resetting/updating the value of the slider, by attaching it to an interval for eg and clearing the interval on click of pause

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},100);
var tim=parseInt($('#slider').slider("option", "value"));
function myTimer()
{
jQuery("#slider").slider({value:tim--});


}


$("#pause").click(function() {
      clearInterval(myVar);
      timer = null
});
```

Comment: OK, but this would mean that I would have more possible values, right? This is not desired, since the slider needs to snap in place for the 24 single images for the last day, respectively 30 single images for the last month.

Comment: @Simon I am unable to understand the snap part, do you mean snap on click? If you could provide a dummy fiddle to play around with would be great.

Comment: OK, you can easily see it when you use the slider on http://lookr.com/1239271528. If you move the handle around, it snaps to predefined positions.